# NanoHTTPD File Upload in a AOSP Project

Tags: android, file-upload, android-source, nanohttpd, embeddedwebserver

I am new to AOSP. I am in an Android TV project. In the project, NanoHTTPD is implemented for Web Applications. What I want to achieve is to be able to send ADB commands, upload files from the local website to the device. I want to achieve it through NanoHTTPD. I looked into NanoFileUpload.java in this [link](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/blob/master/fileupload/src/main/java/org/nanohttpd/fileupload/NanoFileUpload.java) but when I imported jar files for NanoFileUpload, some imported classes couldn't be found in the jar. First I tried to implement Apache FileUpload2 but it wasn't suitable for the Java version of the project, therefore I had to use Apache FileUpload1.2, but it didn't find some of the classes like: " org.apache.commons.fileupload.UploadContext" . Are there any other libraries that I can use to upload files from my pc to the Android TV through NanoHTTPD or should I implement any other web server?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If NanoHTTPD is running on a device then you can upload/post files to NanoHTTPD. I do not understand your problem as you are also talking about local website.

Comment: Hello @blackapps I created a new question for the current problem I have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78198554/timeout-error-while-uploading-file-to-the-android-device